# How to pass a list into message of SNS?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to send an SNS using python. It's working fine. But I want to pass a list into the message body of SNS. How to do that?

I have tried but not working.

```
list = [('9',), ('8',), ('7',), ('6',), ('5',), ('4',), ('3',), ('23',), ('22',), ('21',), ('20',), ('2',), ('19',), ('18',), ('17',), ('16',), ('15',), ('14',), ('13',), ('12',), ('11',), ('10',), ('0',)]

message = { "source": "datapipeline",
            "application_nm": "omni",
            "severity": "2",
            "batch_run_start_dttm": "$actualStartTime",
            "batch_run_end_dttm": "actualEndTime",
            "batch_run_status_cd": "failed",
            "job_orchestration_id": "NA",
            "stage_nm": "NA",
            "stage_start_dttm": "NA",
            "stage_end_dttm": "NA",
            "stage_status_cd":  "failed",
            "job_run_id": "NA",
            "source_nm": "NA",
            "target_nm": "NA",
            "source_details": "NA",
            "target_details": "NA",
            "msg": "These mentioned hours having difference more than 50% from previous week:" +"%s"  ,
            "counts":"0",
            "notes": "After hourly comparison check, the above mentioned hours is having difference more than 50%"
          } %list

try:
    response = client.publish(
    TargetArn=sns_arn,
    Subject = 'Hourly comaprison mismatch',
    Message=json.dumps({'default': json.dumps(message)}),
    MessageStructure='json'
    )
    #return 'servicenow'
except Exception as e:
    return e
    print(e)
    print('SNS is throwing error!')
```

Tried to pass the list value is msg with %s. But throwing an error. How do I pass that list value into JSON format msg body of SNS?

Comment: This is not a question about SNS or AWS, it's just basic Python syntax.

Comment: True ! now the issue in sns. after executing.. its printing elements randomly , how do i print serially as mentioned in message and also put an enter in between two element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
message = { "source": "datapipeline",
            "application_nm": "omni",
            "severity": "2",
            "batch_run_start_dttm": "$actualStartTime",
            "batch_run_end_dttm": "actualEndTime",
            "batch_run_status_cd": "failed",
            "job_orchestration_id": "NA",
            "stage_nm": "NA",
            "stage_start_dttm": "NA",
            "stage_end_dttm": "NA",
            "stage_status_cd":  "failed",
            "job_run_id": "NA",
            "source_nm": "NA",
            "target_nm": "NA",
            "source_details": "NA",
            "target_details": "NA",
            "msg": "These mentioned hours having difference more than 50% from previous week:" +"%s"  ,
            "counts":"0",
            "notes": "After hourly comparison check, the above mentioned hours is having difference more than 50%",
            "list": list # this is how to do it
          }
```

By the way, is a very bad idea to name a variable "list", that clashes with the built-in `list()` function.

Comment: lets assume list as list_test ... still !

Comment: I have no idea what syntax error you're receiving. How about sharing it? Also, did you put a comma at the end of the line before the "list" key?

Comment: now the issue in sns. after executing.. its printing elements randomly , how do i print serially as mentioned in message and also put an enter in between two element

Comment: Order is random when printing elements of a dictionary, this is a Python thing, not SNS’s. Just add ‘\n’ between elements to break lines. Maybe you should post a new question, showing the code you’re using to print, the output you received and the output you expected.